# How to integrate Third party libraries into a Portable Custom Library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have been trying to figure out how to link in CMake and it is making me go crazy. So far I have successfully been able to run my library as an executable(add_executable), but when changing it to a library(add_library) and trying to include it in another project it falls short. The issue is including the third party libraries in my library. The third party libraries are not found and therefore are failed to be included in executable project which results missing libraries. I have tried doing it by statically compiling, but I got lost and fell back to shared libraries.

Basically I am trying to figure out how to compile a library so that its dependencies are portable with the library.

Example Header

```
#ifndef APP_H
#define APP_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>

#include "Class.h"

#include "Vec2.h"
#include "Vec4.h"

using namespace std;

class App{
     /*contents*/
};

#endif
```

Here is my main CMakeList.txt

```
add_subdirectory(extern)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

set(PROJECT_NAME Project)

project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION 0.1.0)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

Here is my source CMakeList.txt

```
file(GLOB HEADER_FILES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")

file(GLOB EXTERN_SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/stb/include/*.h" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/stb/src/*.cpp" )

include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Chassis2D" PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/SDL2/include/" PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/SDL2_ttf" PUBLIC "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/stb/include/")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${EXTERN_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC SDL2 PUBLIC SDL2_ttf PUBLIC box2d)

set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin"
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "when changing it to a library(add_library) and trying to include it in another project it falls short" - Please, add to the question post your **attempt** (code + error message) of inclusion the library into another project.

Comment: https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2017/06/02/using-sdl2-with-cmake/ `The inclusions of these third party libraries don't go over to the final executable project which results missing libraries` What does "don't go over" exactly mean? Please post the error messages. What results in what and which libraries are missing?